# Why is this aggregate function query giving syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to run this code on actual server but it's giving syntax error whereas the same query works perfectly on my localhost. I tried several possibilities but no luck. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

    $first_id = $connection->query("SELECT MIN(id) AS first_id FROM sample")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)['first_id'];
echo $first_id;

?>
```

This is the syntax error I'm getting.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing [array dereferencing](http://www.whileifblog.com/2012/04/25/php-5-4-function-array-dereferencing/) which is only available in PHP 5.4+. You are not running PHP 5.4+.

change

```
$first_id = $connection->query("SELECT MIN(id) AS first_id FROM sample")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)['first_id'];
```

to:

```
$first = $connection->query("SELECT MIN(id) AS first_id FROM sample")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$first_id = $first['first_id'];
```